# Give a function the __LINE__ variable without needing to declare it

Tags: php, lines

So I am trying to make a variable class meaning I can dynamically name my variables. And I wanted to have a `undeclared variable at line x` on my code. I managed to make a function be called like so:

```
function ($varname, $line = 0) {
  // Example
  echo 'unknwon variable found at line '.$line;
}
```

But I wanted to be able to remove the `line = 0` of the function and instead just give it the line without needing to call the function like:

```
exampleFunction('Name', __LINE__);
```

And instead call it like:

```
exampleFunction('Name');
```

And the `__LINE__` variable be passed with it instead of needing to include it. - I tried making the function that was being called look like so:

```
exampleFunction($varname, __LINE__) {
  // Executed code.
}
```

Though that also didn't work out, chucking an error.

Comment: `function exampleFunction($varname, $line = __LINE__) {` but it probably isn't quite what you want

Comment: `chucking an error.` what error exactly?

Comment: I did try that and that's not quite what I wanted, I want to see where the function was called, but thanks :) @MarkBaker

Comment: You can't do it with `__LINE__` as it will return you always the line in the current function.. All you can do is to use [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) but please note that this method is not recommended as it may consume a lot of resources

Comment: But (given the logic in your original function) why not create a custom error handler; the line number value is automatically passed in to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `debug_backtrace` method in your `exampleFunction` to get the caller info with line.

http://php.net/manual/tr/function.debug-backtrace.php

Example (copied from php.net)

```
<?php
// /tmp/a.php dosyası

function a_test($str)
{
    echo "\nHi: $str";
    var_dump(debug_backtrace());
}

a_test('friend');
?>

<?php
// /tmp/b.php dosyası
include_once '/tmp/a.php';
?>
```

Which outputs:

```
Hi: friend
array(2) {
[0]=>
array(4) {
    ["file"] => string(10) "/tmp/a.php"
    ["line"] => int(10)
    ["function"] => string(6) "a_test"
    ["args"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0] => &string(6) "friend"
    }
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
    ["file"] => string(10) "/tmp/b.php"
    ["line"] => int(2)
    ["args"] =>
    array(1) {
      [0] => string(10) "/tmp/a.php"
    }
    ["function"] => string(12) "include_once"
  }
}
```